# ProgrammingError: column mail_template.built_in does not exist LINE 1: ...as "report_template","mail_template"."id" as "id","mail_temp

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-10

```
ProgrammingError: column mail_template.built_in does not exist
LINE 1: ...as "report_template","mail_template"."id" as 
"id","mail_temp...
                                                         ^
```

I am receiving an error when uninstalling a module (website_support).

There is no error when upgrading this module.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything inheriting off of the module that isn't uninstalling with it?